# How to add different values in the same row with conditionals of date - google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a file where I keep track of the sessions that I have with clients. **The issue is that I have 1 row for each client **and in different columns I register the date and in another one how was the meeting.

Remember: Each client has its own row. I want to know the date of each session with each mode per year

For example

Name: John Doe - Session 1: 04/04/2021 - Mode: Virtual - Sessión 2: 05/04/2021 - Mode: P2P - Session 3: 04/04/2022 - Mode: Virtual

What I want to know if how can I know how many sessions where given in 2021 and 2022 and with which mode (example: 2 sessions in 2021 - Virtual 1 / P2P 1; 1 session in 2022 - 1 virtual)

I add a picture of my sheet:
[Google sheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVVNB.png)

I tried count if but I can only get how many sessions where given in a time (2 sessions in 2021 and 1 in 2022) but I don't know which mode was each session

This is my formula how I know the dates: =CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO(AN2:CX2,">="&FECHA(2022,1,1),AN2:CX2,"<="&FECHA(2022,12,31)) but this formula does not tell me the mode.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to add a copy of your images of a table as a markup table? See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how.

Comment: Following with @starball, could you specify how and where do you expect to have your result represented?

Comment: It can be anywhere. To tell you the truth, I am using DataStudio so it can be in a new column. I will leave a a link here to an example of how is the data right now (the formula is in column FI) - [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZKEnS7t5IX-IB_u9StWwJAbiVbYIMerU84lYoHKqe7I/edit?usp=sharing)